# Install php-pecl-memcached

Tags: php, centos, memcached

I'm trying to install php-pecl-memcached in php v5.4.45 and Centos v6.5.

My command is following.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pecl-memcached
```

However I encountered the following error.

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libhashkit.so.2.0.0 conflicts between attempted installs of libmemcached-last-libs-1.0.18-2.el6.remi.x86_64 and libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libmemcached.so.11.0.0 conflicts between attempted installs of libmemcached-last-libs-1.0.18-2.el6.remi.x86_64 and libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libmemcachedutil.so.2.0.0 conflicts between attempted installs of libmemcached-last-libs-1.0.18-2.el6.remi.x86_64 and libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64
```

I tried remove libmemcached10 by the following command.

```
yum remove libmemcached10
```

However, It doesn't work. The error detaile is following.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: libmemcached10
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * epel: mirrors.hustunique.com
 * extras: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * ius: archive.linux.duke.edu
 * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
Package(s) libmemcached10 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both "remi" and "IUS" repositories

So: remove libmemcached10 (from IUS) and retry.

Notice PHP 5.4 is now EOL. IUS have remove it from its repository, while it is still available in "remi", with security fix backported from 5.5. In all case, an upgrade to a maintained version is strongly recommended.

See: http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So you said by updating php version from 5.4 to 5.5, my problem will be solved?

Comment: No. Different issues. To install php-pecl-memcached from "remi" repo you have to remove libmemcached from "ius".  Upgrade to 5.5 or 5.6 is just a notice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my question , I cannot remove php-peck-memcached by the command "yum remove libmemcached10". Could you tell me how to remove it?

Comment: Hard to help without the full yum output. Try disabling IUS to avoid conflicting repositories